# Office js recipientType discrepancy for Outlook on Windows

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We use Office.js to build an Outlook web add-in and we make use of the calls `composeItem.to.getAsync` where the compose Item is `Office.context.mailbox.item`. The call returns an array of recipients of `Office.EmailAddressDetails` objects and are as described in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.emailaddressdetails?view=outlook-js-preview&viewFallbackFrom=office-js#recipienttype).

In the latest version(s) of Windows Outlook (**16.0.11901.20204 and 16.0.11901.20070**), we can observe a discrepancy in the resulting `EmailAddressDetails.recipientType` to the above call when it comes to **Dynamic Distribution Groups**. We observe that the `recipientType` used to be `distributionList` on a slightly older version of Windows Outlook (**16.0.11328.20362**). But now, the `recipientType` returns `other` for Dynamic Distribution Groups. This discrepancy affects clients that are on different Windows Outlook update cycles.

Is this change going to be permanent or will it be using a value something other than `other`?

This affects how we implement our web add-in because we're concerned with figuring out groups (distribution lists, DDGs, etc.) from users and expanding the groups. As it stands right now, we're unsure whether `other` is within the category of expandable groups or not as there is no documentation regarding the details of `recipientType` values.